# Strange happenings in the barren wastes of visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

So I was just happily going along defining a new class when this happend:

```
class Thing : public OtherThing
{
public:
    Thing : public OtherThing();//here
};
```

I really have no idea why visual assist/studio did this and i've never seen it before so really my question is what does it mean?

Just for the sake of clarity I would normally define the same class like this:

```
class Thing : public OtherThing
{
public:
    Thing();
};
```

Comment: Doesn't compile, so random auto complete nonsense.

Comment: Hmmm, It compiles on my end, do you mind if I see your compile error?

Comment: How can this ever compile? Missing semicolon after class, and class-level `Thing : public OtherThing();//here` is definitely not C++?

Comment: Corrected, I just wanted to provide a small, verifiable example but was low on time. And Yes I'm fairly sure visual assist just had a bit of a moment based on the replies; thanks for the replies :)

Comment: @GeorgePurcell Make clean, to eliminate other (precompiled) glitches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`public`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access) keyword is defined in 2 contexts:

1. Deferring access to members of a base class to the access level they were declared with:

> When a class uses `public` member access specifier to derive from a base, all `public` members of the base class are accessible as `public` members of the derived class and all `protected` members of the base class are accessible as `protected` members of the derived class (`private` members of the base are never accessible unless friended)<sup>[[source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/derived_class#Public_inheritance)]</sup>

2. Specifying the access level for all members declared following this specifier

> Public members form a part of the public interface of the class (other parts of the public interface are the non-member functions found by Argument-Dependent Lookup).
>   A public member of a class is accessible everywhere.<sup>[[source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access#Public_member_access)]</sup>

Since the code you have demonstrated is not declaring inheritance (**1**) or specifying member access (**2**) it is an invalid use of the keyword and should not compile.

I see your statement that [this compiles for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38765068/strange-happenings-in-the-barren-wastes-of-visual-studio#comment64902258_38765068), but indeed this cannot compile in gcc: http://ideone.com/Z33viJ or in Visual Studio 2015, which you can validate by going here: http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/ The only plausible explanation that I can come up with is there is a malfunction in which the code your editor is showing you is not what has been written to the file and thus is not what's being compiled. If this is the case perhaps a restart of Visual Studio would solve the problem.

Comment: Hmmm, this is very strange. I restarted vs and the project no longer compiled, I then re-defined the class and VA auto-complete did the same thing and again did not compile. I think it was just a combination of visual studio having a bit of a moment and a weird visual assist bug. Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: @GeorgePurcell Though not as robust as Visual Assist, Visual Studio 2015 has finally extended the "insert" context menu to C++ users. Though I won't deny it's usefulness the usefulness gap between native Visual Studio and Visual Assist is shrinking dramatically. I believe this is a small example of why Visual Assist will soon be as worthless as a CD player.